# Create array with weighted items inserted at intervals

Tags: php, jquery

I'm developing a messaging board for use in a client's lobby.

The "rundown" is JSON created from PHP, which is checked for updates by an AJAX call every 5 minutes. The rundown is populated from a MySQL database that contains the item, its duration and a start and stop time. JQuery iterates through the content then loops to the beginning of the data. Currently no items repeat within the list.

A weighting system has been requested, so that when an important item ($$$ client, staff meeting, etc) is present it appears more frequently in the list (instead of just once until the loop occurs).

I've added a weight column to the database, but am having trouble figuring out how to implement that in my final array build:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($rundown_standard as $item) {
            $return[$i]["playlist_id"] = $i;
            $return[$i]["item_id"] = $item["id"];
            $return[$i]["weight"] = $item["weight"];
            $return[$i]["duration"] = $item["duration"];
            $return[$i]["template"] = $item["template"];
            $return[$i]["headline"] = htmlentities($item["headline"]);

        $content = $helper->isJson($item["content"]);
        if ($content) {
            $return[$i]["content"] = $content; 
        } else { 
            $return[$i]["content"] = str_replace(array('{images_path_absolute}', '{images_path_relative}'), array(IMAGES_PATH_ABSOLUTE, IMAGES_PATH_RELATIVE), $item["content"]);
        }

    i++;
}
```

`$return` is the formatted data I'm sending on to the function that calls this function.

The default weight is `0` which means it should be shown only once in the order it's added to the array, something with a weight of `90` should appear after every other item.

I've tried setting another counter variable and then inserting the item and resetting the counter, which would work for just one weighted item, but not for multiple weighted items

Clear as mud?

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT 17:45: The JavaScript is just to update the page dynamically; iterating through the JSON and appending the next item to a list:

```
if (window.item_content[i].template == "1") {
    return '<div class="featured-item" id="featured-item-'+window.item_content[i].playlist_id+'"><img src="'+window.item_content[i].content+'" /></div>';
}
```

It's the array where my problem lies, precisely how do I insert an element at a specified interval if there are multiple elements to insert.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you know how to code, and just need an algorithm, so I'll offer you some pseudo-code.  If you need me to turn it into better code, I can do so.

1. Work with two arrays: `return` and `highPriority`.  `return` won't care about the weight, while `highPriority` will.
2. Iterate through your given list, and put all 0 weights into `return` and all others into `highPriority`.
3. Sort `highPriority` on the weight, from lowest to highest.
4. Foreach item in `highPriority`, the math ends up easy, but comes from a typical "normalize and scale" operation: normalize the weight (`n = weight / 90`), then scale it to the size of the array (`n *= return.length`) to find the number of items you want to add into the array.  Then to find how much space is necessary to distribute the items in the `return` array, you would do `return.length / n`.  This boils down simply to `90/weight`, though!

   1. `var step = 90 / item.weight;`
   2. `for (var i = 0; i <= 90; i += step) place item at i[step]`

Things to note:

- We start with the zero weight, because they're low priority and only have to exist once.
- For all the others, since they're higher weight, we start them at the *front* of the array.
- The `step` we calculated will change for each element, since return.length changes in each iteration, but since we're adding highest priority ones last, they'll still get the most precedence.
- We use `i <= 90` to make sure that these weighted values will appear at least twice.  If it was only `i < 90`, and the weight was 1, we could end up with only one item, and weight 1 should be different than weight 0.
- I haven't fully checked out this algorithm.  We may need some `Math.floor` or `Math.ceiling` in the calculation of step.  Check your edge cases (better than I did)!

That should get you going.  Hope it helps!